# I don't understand the error message 'NoneType' object is not iterable in python

Tags: python, list, typeerror

```
def make_list_of_lists(n):
    the_list = []
    sublist = []
    for i in range(n):
        print(sublist)
        the_list.extend(sublist)
        sublist = sublist.insert(len(sublist), i+1)
    return the_list
```

I got a error message of this function, which is:

> 'NoneType' object is not iterable'

I don't understand why this happen?

Comment: Please give us the exact error with a full traceback.

Comment: You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 4):

Look at this line:

```
sublist = sublist.insert(len(sublist), i+1)
```

`insert` function does insert in place and returns `None`, so on next iteration here

```
the_list.extend(sublist)
```

`sublist` is `None` while `extend` function requires iterable parameter. Fixed code:

```
def make_list_of_lists(n):
    the_list = []
    sublist = []
    for i in range(n):
        print(sublist)
        the_list.extend(sublist)
        sublist.insert(len(sublist), i + 1)
    return the_list

make_list_of_lists(3)
```

> []
>
> [1]
>
> [1, 2]
>
> [1, 1, 2]

Answer (score 1):

The `insert` operation modifying the object inplace, and like a almost all of these kind of method it returns `None` because you don't need the return value. After 1 iteration it tried to do the following which requires to iterate over `None` to add all of its elements, and you can't

```
the_list.extend(None)
```

So just do

```
sublist.insert(len(sublist), i + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sublist = sublist.insert(len(sublist), i+1)
```

This makes sublist to be none. That is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in other answers, it is the `sublist = sublist.insert(len(sublist), i+1)` line that causes the problem.

However, you seem to be wanting to make a list of lists (based on the function name), which your code currently does not do.

```
def make_list_of_lists(n):
      the_list = []
      sublist = []
      for i in range(n):
          the_list.append(sublist)
      return the_list

print(make_list_of_lists(5))
```

This prints an empty list of 5 empty lists:

```
[[], [], [], [], []]
```